# How to find and delete this file by name series

Tags: linux, ls

List of files in one of my directories as per date is:

```
2015-08-28 12:05 A01.tar
 2015-08-28 11:31 A02.tar
 2015-08-28 10:26 A03.tar
 2015-08-28 10:16 A04.tar
 2015-08-28 07:26 A05.tar
 2015-08-28 00:26 A06.tar
 2015-08-28 00:26 A07.tar
 2015-08-27 16:14 AA01.tar
 2015-08-27 14:58 CV03.tar
 2015-08-27 11:59 CV04.tar
 2015-08-27 11:32 CV05.tar
 2015-08-27 11:22 CV07.tar
 2015-08-27 11:12 CV08.tar
 2015-08-27 11:32 CV09.tar
```

Now i want to keep only the 5 newest files of each series (series = CV, A, AA). for example I want to delete

```
CV09.tar
A06.tar
A07.tar
```

And keep the rest. Should i use of "wc -l" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Find command. Similar to this

```
find /var/log/httpd/ -name "*CV.tar" -mtime +5 -delete
```